# How long after a long run can one (body weight) exercise?

Tags: running, bodyweight-exercises, recovery

Is it a good idea to engage in relatively heavy session of upper body + core calisthenics (read, push-ups/pull-ups/chin-ups) about 12 hours after a long run (10k+) - assuming one is feeling fine and not exhausted, but heart rate still a bit high?

If not, how much gap is ideal? Should one wait till the heart rate comes completely back to normal?

Comment: Why are you concerned? Do you just randomly wonder if it is good for you or do you have a reason to believe it is not?

Comment: I believe I've noticed I can exercise better (more reps, better results) if I start from rest than if I do it shortly after a good run. So I ask to check that exercising in the evening after a morning run is a good idea, or if it is best to simply stagger the days..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run first, you’ll do better at the run and have better results from it, while the body weight work won’t be quite as good as it could be. Vice versa for doing the body weight stuff first. Depending on your intensity, you could do one right after the other. In your question you ask about doing them separately with 12 hours of time between them which is more than enough assuming that you’ve got the proper nutrition supporting your efforts.

As for how low your heart rate should be? Low enough to be able to speak and have a halfway decent conversation. I don’t see any reason why you couldn’t jump straight into body weight work after 20 minutes or less.